# Change opacity of 2 elements to give a crossfade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am working on some functionality for an e-commerce where by a user clicks a products colour, and the previous image of the products fades out while the new product fades, I am trying to achieve a cross fade effect, however I have flicker effect in there which I do not want, I think it comes when I am removing the old image from the dom, here is a fiddle to show you what I trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/L9Z5G/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you were looking for: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bKYwV/1/)

```
$('.colours').click(function() {
  if ($('#' + $(this).html().toLowerCase()).attr('class') == 'active') { return; }

  var active = $('.active');
  var next = $('#' + $(this).html().toLowerCase());

  active.fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  next.fadeIn(500, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it not easier to use .hide() and .show(), and just let them crossfade themselves?

Answer (score 1):

To bind a click event, you use click() heres how.

```
$('#color1').click(function(){
      $('#image1').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this please: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/djMZe/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/R7u8G/1/

Hope it fits the needs! `:)`

**code**

```
$("#colours li").click(function() {
    $(".large-image:first-child:not(.new)").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500);
    var img = $("<img />").attr('src', $(this).data("alternative")).attr("class", "large-image new");
    img.css({
        opacity: 0
    })
    $(".zoom-image").append(img);
    //img.animate({ opacity    :    1}, 500);
    img.css({
        "opacity": "1"
    }).fadeIn("slow");
    $(".large-image:not(:last-child)").remove();

});​
```

Comment: thanks but your solution just swaps the image I was wanting the swap to have a nice fade effect.

Comment: @sico87: See my answer hopefully it will be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

See This [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/jwnWU/), hope you've required this effect.

**EDITED:** [**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/ZKgnR/10/)

**jQuery Cycle Plugin**

```
$('#slideshow').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 'fast',
    timeout: 0,
    pager: '#nav',

    // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';
    }
});​
```

[**SEE REFERENCE**](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Comment: Thanks but the user does not click thumbnails they click color swatches so how would I link it in to my existing system?